# URL is redirecting (301) when query string is passed through URL

Tags: redirect

301 redirection is happening and redirected URL is losing the parameters while passing query strings via URL.

When I try to pass the query string “type=Brochure” as shown in below URL
https://www.edgeverve.com/resources/?type=Brochure

It is getting redirected to https://www.edgeverve.com/resources/
and query the string is lost.

But it is working fine if I change the subdomain from www 
(both www and test URLs are available for testing, try replacing www with test)

I am unable to figure out why this redirection is happening in the case of www.

**Note:**
We could not fix the issue even after following steps below:
– All URLs in DB are proper.
– We tried the same setup in localhost (with host file entry mapping to edgeverve.com)
– We tried updating WordPress to 4.8
– Also, we tried to handle it via .htaccess

Answer (score -1):

The issue got resolved by disabling Yoast SEO plugin. What would be the reason for Yoast SEO plugin to cause this issue?